# Css not showing on android phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

On my page, if I view it through the web browser, I can see this effect:

```
.voted {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:blue;
 }
```

Which shows the blue border. However if I view the page through the phone, I don't see this effect.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

I am mainly interesting in showing some visual effect that shows in all client devices. If there is some easy way to show this using jquery mobile or something, can anyone post the code?

Comment: `border: 1px solid blue;` ?

Comment: I guess you missed to `border-width`?  have you tried like`border-width: 1px` or `border: 1px solid blue`?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the width of the border.

CSS:-

```
.voted{
 border:7px solid blue;
 }
```

Instead of solid,you can even try with various other designs like dashed etc to play around with it